# Extract value from config.json (Python)

Tags: python

Usually my project directory structure look like:

```
project_name/
 lib/
  utils.py
 logs/
 main.py
 requirements.txt
 config.json
```

My config.json file looks like:

```
{
    "api": {
        "api_key": "abcdefg",
        "api_secret": "hijklmn"
    },
    "trading": {
        "invest_amount": 50,
        "mode": "futures",
        "cumulative_position": false
    }
}
```

In utils.py, I have a class `Config`

```
import typing
import inspect
import os
import json
from typing import Any


class Config(object):
    _CONFIG_FILE: typing.Optional[str] = None
    _CONFIG: typing.Optional[dict] = None

    def __init__(self):
        config_file = Config.get_config_path(frame=inspect.stack()[1])
        with open(config_file, 'r') as f:
            Config._CONFIG = json.load(f)

    @staticmethod
    def get_config_path(frame: inspect.FrameInfo, config_file_name: str = "config.json") -> str:
        caller_file_name = frame[0].f_code.co_filename
        caller_folder_name = os.path.dirname(caller_file_name)
        config_file_name = os.path.join(caller_folder_name, config_file_name)
        return config_file_name

    @staticmethod
    def get_config_value(param: str) -> Any:
        for key in Config._CONFIG.keys():
            value = Config._CONFIG.get(key).get(param, None)
            if value is not None:
                return value
        raise ValueError(f"{param} doesn't exist")
```

And I will use it in main.py usually:

```
from lib.utils import Config


def main(trading_mode, invest_amount, cumulative_position):
    print(trading_mode, invest_amount, cumulative_position)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = Config()
    main(trading_mode=config.get_config_value(param="mode"),
         invest_amount=config.get_config_value(param="invest_amount"),
         cumulative_position=config.get_config_value(param="cumulative_position"))
```

Is there any code that can improve or rewrite in class `Config`, for the purpose of efficiency, readability or clear logic, etc?

Comment: I think this is over-engineered. Just load a config file from an explicit path and use the `dict` returned by `json.load()`.

Comment: Do you mean using `with open("config.json", "r")`? How should I store the desired values and input these into `main()`? Should I constructure a function like `config.get_config_value` for this?

Comment: How is assigning a `dict` to a variable `config` any different from assigning an instance of `Config` to such a variable? And given your config is a dict, you can just use `cofig.get(key)` instead of `config.get_config_value(key)`.

Comment: Can you post the correction on how should I edit the `class Config` or using `config.get(key)`? It's a bit confusing for me to understand the words, better in answer the question instead of comment, it would be helpful, many thanks!

Comment: seems very complex for a simple read function?

Comment: Any alternative suggests to replace it? @Barb

Comment: using a 'with open' function that handles most of the functionality might be a bit more dynamic and practical when handling larger files. If you can parse the information in to csv and then convert it to any format you want it to read from there. They can be stored as simple text files but still massively encrypted.

Comment: def __init__(self): - for instance can be used as a non destructive super script so instead of making subclasses, you can reiterate the same parent class without changing the whole function. That will allow you to use the main functions code to do everything pretty much

Comment: Would you write it in answer with some example instead please since I'm a bit confused on how I can actually apply what you suggested. @Barb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The good parts

You code is very readable. You stick to PEP 8 for the most part (except the annoying line length limitation) and use reasonable naming.

### Managing configuration

Your first mistake, imho, is that you make the config part of the project.
Having the config in the project's repo, especially if it contains things like `api_secret` (or `password` etc.) is a common source for secret leakage via repo hosting services such as Git{Hub,Lab}.

### Load config explicitly.

Currently, one of the first things your script `main.py` does is to read data from the file system. Though this is not immediately visible to the reader, since it is hidden in `Config.__init__()`.

You can write a simple function like

```py
from json import load
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any

...

def load_config(filename: Path | str) -> dict[str, Any]:
    """Load configuration from a JSON file."""

    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        return load(file)
```

to load configuration from a JSON file by explicitly specifying it's path and use the returned `dict`.

### If you have JSON, use JSON

Python's `json` library already does all the work to parse JSON objects into associative arrays aka. `dict`s. Use them directly to access the desired data:

```py
from lib.utils import Config


def main(trading_mode, invest_amount, cumulative_position):
    print(trading_mode, invest_amount, cumulative_position)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = load_config('/path/to/my/config.json')
    trading_cfg = config.get('trading')
    main(
        trading_mode=trading_cfg.get('mode'),
        invest_amount=trading_cfg.get('invest_amount'),
        cumulative_position=trading_cfg.get('cumulative_position')
    )
```

All the introspection automagic might feel comfortable at first, but it hides away a lot of potential side-effects.
Furthermore, it won't be needed anyways if you separate your configuration from your project source code.

Comment: I usually add `config.json` into `.ignore` when using github/gitlab, is there any better alternative for that? If using the `load_config` function you suggested, will it be a bit slower or redundant to read the config file path everytime I call the function, e.g. I need to extract ten values in `config.json` then I need to use `with open(file_name, "rb")` ten times.

Comment: @tung have a read about [dotenv files](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)

Comment: but I am using config.json instead of .env @GrajdeanuAlex